# Conditional covariance in gaussian graphical models

Tags: probability, graph-theory, normal-distribution, random-graphs

I have a hypothesis, but I'm not sure if its true.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Applications_to_probability_theory_and_statistics) states that if the covariance matrix is given by 
$$\Sigma=\left[\begin{matrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{matrix}\right]$$
the conditional covariance matrix is given by 
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X\mid Y) = A-BC^{-1}B^T$$

Slide 23 in this [presentation](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~steffen/teaching/gm11/covsel.pdf) on graphical models states that 
$$K_{11}^{-1}=\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}$$
which is the same as the above formula!

So it seems like there is an elegant way to find the covariance of $X|Y$. Simply look at the corresponding block in the precision (inverse covariance) matrix and take its inverse. Is this true? If it is, it seems like such a cool result. Why can't I see it explicitly spelled out anywhere?